# Change class from different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes, ng-class, ng-view

I have my index.html page in which an ng-view is implemented. The same applies to the sidebar, which also linkes to 3 pages (main.html, product.html and customer.html).

I need to change the class of sidebar.html for example when I'm in the customer.html page.

I tried to do it from the customerController but it had no result. As I understand it, because the sidebar.html is controlled by MyController
Can anyone guide me?
Thank you

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="appDataBoard">
  <body ng-controller="MyController" >
     <!-- SIDEBAR-->
     <div ng-include="'./template/sidebar.html'" ></div>
      <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
         <div class="page-content-wrapper">
              <div class="col-md-12 column sortable">
                  <div ng-view></div>
              </div>
          </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
   <ul >
      <li class="nav-item start open">
          <a href="#/main" class="nav-link nav-toggle"> </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item  ">
           <a href="#/product" class="nav-link nav-toggle"></a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="nav-item">
           <a href="#/customer" class="nav-link nav-toggle"></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- END SIDEBAR -->
```

**routing.js**

```
var dbApp = angular.module('appDataBoard', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);

// configure our routes
    dbApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/main', {
                templateUrl : 'template/main.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/product', {
                templateUrl : 'template/product.html',
                controller  : 'productController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/customer', {
                templateUrl : 'template/customer.html',
                controller  : 'customerController'
            });
    });
```